# angularJs templating

Tags: templates, angularjs

I'm new to angular and I'm looking for a way to achive more advanced templating that one mentioned in the tutorial [here](http://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_07)

1.) I would like to have a different template for the login page and another one after you are logined

2.) it would be nice to have a functionality of multiple ng-view-s so you can have diferent pieces of the template filed diferently on every url...is it possible to achive this in angular

3.) is there a beter/easyer templating mechanisem to use, meybe some other js framework?

The ideall would be to use something like facelets but on client.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest looking into [ui-router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router) for doing nested views.

Answer (score 2):

While it is not possible to have multiple ng-views, you can certainly have more than one routes, each one mapped to a controller and a view. It will help to do further reading on how to use controllers, routes etc. You can also use ng-include one ore more times with static or dynamic template urls mapped to a variable in the controller.

AngularJS is one of the best (if not the best) multi-feature JS UI frameworks available in terms of MVCness, extensibility, fine tuning, testing, data binding, templating etc. You cannot generally go wrong with it, just need to spend some time initially getting used to the patterns, idioms and terminology.

Comment: do you maybe know of any good example of complex templating with angular, I would like to see some example code